# Moving <li> to another list need to update click listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

See an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/06bf3w2c/1/

I have two `<ul>`s. Clicking an item in the second one will move that item to the first one.

In the first list each `<li>` contains a `<span>` with the class `delete-btn`. when this span gets clicked it should remove the item from the list.

This is working correctly except for when you move an item from the second list into the first list *and then* try to delete it. Once the delete-btn span of a moved item gets clicked it seems to still be registering the click listener for the second list even though it is no longer in the second list.

My click listener is applied like this:

```
$(".second li").click(function(){
  $(".first").append($(this).append(' <span class="delete-btn">[ X ]</span>'));
});
```

after the li is moved and then the delete-btn span is clicked it calls this click listener even though the `<li>` no longer is a decedent to the `second` class.

How can I update the click listener when I move the `<li>` from the second list to the first so that the delete button listener will work after the item has been moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're attaching the click listener to the `li`'s themselves.  When the li is moved, it still has the click event listener and just duplicates itself. You should instead attach the event listeners to the lists and have it listen for clicks on child `li`s like so:

```js
$(".second").on('click', 'li', function(){
  $(".first").append($(this).append(' <span class="delete-btn">[ X ]</span>'));
});

$(".first").on('click', '.delete-btn', function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```css
ul{
  float: left;
}

.second li{
  background-color: #BABABA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="first">
<li>item 1 <span class="delete-btn">[ X ]</span></li>
<li>item 2 <span class="delete-btn">[ X ]</span></li>
</ul>

<ul class="second">
<li>item 3</li>
<li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you know how I can make it so that when I click an item in the second list it doesn't get removed from that list? So it would get copied and added to the first, but also remain in second.

Comment: @FoamyGuy Instead of `$(this).append(' <span class="delete-btn">[ X ]</span>')` use `$(this).clone().append(' <span class="delete-btn">[ X ]</span>')`.  Might need `clone(true)` or `clone(true, true)` if you have event listeners you *do* want duplicated over.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, appreciate the help.